# CSS: Change color on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover, background-color

So I have been working on a website with clickable images, but I can't seem to get the `...:hover` right. I want that the picture gets overlayed by white color with 0.1 opacity.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
        img {
            margin-top: -10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        }
        #asca:hover {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}
        #fhca:hover {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}
        #asca img:hover {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}
        #fhca img:hover {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="asca" href="asc.php">
        <img src="Pictures/chevcorvette4kp.png" width="4096" height="900"  alt="ascpic">
    </a>
    <a id="fhca" href="fhc.php">
        <img src="Pictures/fhyper.png" width="4096" height="900"  alt="fhcpic"> 
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I really tried to change everything to that color upon hover, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work, because you have not actually put anything “over”, in front of, the image yet - you are just changing background colors _behind_ the image. You need to place a (pseudo) element on top of your image first, and then you can modify the background of that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using opacity, the background won't take effect..

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img {
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

a:hover img {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

#asca:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#fhca:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#asca img:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

#fhca img:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<a id="asca" href="asc.php">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"   alt="ascpic">
</a>
<a id="fhca" href="fhc.php">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"   alt="fhcpic"> 
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but i also have a white border between the images after removing "margin-top: -10px;". Do you know a fix by any chance?

Comment: Sorry that i dont have enough rep to be able to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because the image is covering its own `background-color`. There are a few ways to achieve the effect you're after, but the easiest and most straight-forward is to just use a `background-color` on the anchor tags, and change opacity on the image on hover.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
        img {
            margin-top: -10px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        #asca,
        #fhca {
            background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
        }

        #asca:hover img,
        #fhca:hover img {
            opacity: 0.9;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a id="asca" href="asc.php">
        <img src="Pictures/chevcorvette4kp.png" width="4096" height="900"  alt="ascpic">
    </a>
    <a id="fhca" href="fhc.php">
        <img src="Pictures/fhyper.png" width="4096" height="900"  alt="fhcpic"> 
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thx! Worked too! Sorry i dont have enough rep to upvote :(.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your CSS **is the background color that is set on hover is *behind* the foreground image and is never visible because the foreground image blocks it**.

Keeping your current HTML, if you update your CSS to something like this, it achieves the effect you're going for. (Notable bits of CSS commented)

```
<style>
    body {padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    img {
        margin-top: -10px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    a {
        background-color: #fff; /* Give the <a> tag a white background */
    }
    a:hover img {
        opacity: .9; /* reduce the transparency of the foreground image by 10%, allowing the white background to show through 10%. */
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test now but you can try to use z-index properties.

```
img {
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 0;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
a {
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
a:before{
    content: "";
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.78);
    opacity: 0;
    transition:all ease .3s;
}
a:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
}
```